# Are two copies of bootstrap.css supposed to be generated by Compass when using bootstrap-sass?

Tags: css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, compass-sass, bootstrap-sass

I am trying to set up a ruby web project using [sinatra](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra) (1.4.5), [slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim) (2.0.3), [sass](https://github.com/sass/sass) (3.4.0) and [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) (3.2.0.1) gems.

Since I am using Sass, I decided to try out the [compass](https://github.com/Compass/compass) (1.0.1) gem to automatically generate `.css` from my `.scss` files.

I followed directions on the [bootstrap-sass github page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#b-compass-without-rails) to use with compass, namely:

```
compass create my-new-project -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap
```

However, I noticed that this always generates 2 copies of `bootstrap.css` (which `git diff` tells me are the same except for file paths since they are in different directories):

```
... (other files/directories get made and written)
directory my-new-project/stylesheets/bootstrap
    write my-new-project/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.css
directory my-new-project/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap
    write my-new-project/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap/bootstrap.css
```

Is this the intended behavior of this installation? If so, why are 2 copies of `bootstrap.css` desirable? If not, how can I get compass to stop generating 2 copies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is being worked on in `Unnecessary file in assets` [git issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/686)  and [pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/pull/693). It should no longer be an issue in the next release of the `bootstrap-sass` gem, as `glebm` mentions in the pull request.

As described in the pull request mentioned above, a simple fix to this annoyance is simply removing `assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss` within the `bootstrap-sass` gem.